# Drupal 7 regions

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

So I am getting acquainted with Drupal and it hasn't been a smooth ride so far. 
What I understand is that Drupal 7 has a few regions such as Header, Navigation, sidebar first and sidebar second.

Essentially Sidebar first and Sidebar second manage to create some space around the content and navigation and footer. I do not want these sidebars because I want my content and navigations to occupy the full width, essentially I have no use for Drupal sidebars and don't want them to exist.

However, I am clueless on how I can remove these, anybody have a clue how we can remove the sidebar regions. This also grows another question, how can I manipulate the width and breadth of a region ?

Thanks much guys!

Answer (score 1):

When you add content in Drupal, the sidebar regions will not be expressed unless you place content in them.  You define what goes in each region using Admin/structures/blocks in Drupal 7.

Drupal is not easy to understand for the uninitiated, and documentation on Drupal site is not a comprehensive tutorial.  The best way to get a handle on Drupal is to get an introductory book at Amazon or your library.  If you are video oriented, I recommend the series on Lynda.com (but it is subscription based).  There are other tutorials scattered around the web and maybe some other readers of this question can provide suggestions.

This site is very active and is a great resource for getting answers regarding Drupal. As you get into Drupal, I'm sure there will be more questions :)  People on this site are very helpful and you can thank them by recognizing good answers by clicking the 'Up' button or giving them a check mark if you recognize their answer as the one you accept.

Good Luck

Comment: The link to the page JoeS is talking about is (http://example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fstructure%252Fblock) but replace example.com with your site ;)

Comment: Oh, and you can see the various regions the theme you're using has on that page, click on "Demonstrate block regions [theme_name]" (http://example.com/?q=admin/structure/block/demo/bartik#overlay-context=) (Bartik theme, for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking into theming your site, try playing with [Framework](http://drupal.org/project/framework) or [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen). These are base themes from which you can build upon (and starting out, you will want to :)

You can easily switch between themes from the Appearance admin page ([http://example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fappearance](http://example.com/#overlay=?q=admin%252Fappearance)) so feel free to install a few and look at the differences.

When you're moving content around, be sure to look at the Admin Bar/Structure/Blocks page that JoeS talked about (links in comments)

A word of caution though: Templates have a LOT of power opened up to them in Drupal, don't go too far without becoming accustomed to "the Drupal way" first. Trust me :) (Ex: install some modules, like [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views))

Answer (score 1):

In the .info file of your (active or un-active) theme folder you can set your regions, and also delete them.

For example this code below simply does not display the sidebars since it is not declared in the .info file.

```
regions[header]       = 'Header'
regions[main_prefix]  = 'Main Region Prefix'
regions[content]      = 'Main Region'
regions[main_suffix]  = 'Main Region Suffix'
regions[footer]       = 'Footer'
```